# Multiple return type from function - C++

Tags: c++, c++17

Is there any way (conventional or no) to get a choice between multiple specified return types from a function. For example:

```
/* Concept code... */
class var {
    public:
        union {
            bool _bool;
            int _int;
            char* _char_pointer;
        } primitive_value;
        std::string type;

        var(bool arg) { primitive_value._bool = arg; type = "bool"; }
        var(int arg) { primitive_value._int = arg; type = "int"; }
        var(char* arg) { primitive_value._char_pointer = arg; type = "char*"; }

        // Function/ method that could return `bool`, `int` or `char*`
        <bool, int, char*> valueOf() const {
            if (type == "bool") return primitive_value._bool;
            else if (type == "int") return primitive_value._int;
            else if (type == "char*") return primitive_value._char_pointer;
        }
};
```

There is a reference to a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28563015/function-pointers-with-different-return-types-c) I've seen that suggested using `void*` pointers or `union`'s but I have yet to fully understand how those work.

No container types (such as `std::any`, `std::optional`, `std::variant`) are allowed because I want to know if there is an alternative to those as well.

To add on, this is all in the name of **curiosity**. Currently I am searching the `optional` and `variant` header files to know how the feature I'm asking for was implemented but no luck so far.

I'm hoping the platform here could have a practical solution to this potential problem.

Comment: `std::variant` just does what you are asking. you could implement it yourself if you really want

Comment: The example code you show looks like a bad design. And why can't you use e.g. `std::any` or `std::variant`? How about templates (possibly with specialization)?

Comment: I'm trying to understand how `std::variant` handles returning multiple types from its constructors. I'm just curious as to how the internal code works.

Comment: how would you call the function? Lets say you make it return different types, then also the caller has to be able to handle different types. Whatever you do it will be either complicated or broken or both. I agree that this is probably not the best design

Comment: See this: https://arne-mertz.de/2018/05/modern-c-features-stdvariant-and-stdvisit/

Comment: is `type` known at compile time?

Comment: the problem is that you can't compare strings at compile time

Comment: In your code `type` is _not_ known at compile time @OP

Comment: @StackDanny. Yea, a slight mistake on my part.

Comment: @Lapys well, then you can't use any `if constexpr`. You will have to use `void*` but the problem with that is that, as already mentioned, the user will have to `reinterpret_cast<T*>()` in order to use it. Which makes the whole `type` Thing useless.

Comment: @palotasb Thank you for the resource: arne-mertz.de/2018/05/modern-c-features-stdvariant-and-stdvisit.

Comment: @Lapys there won't be a suitable solution to your problem unless they change C++ to a weakly-typed programming language. You will have to use another design here.

Comment: @StackDanny Lol. You're right about that. This really was just curiosity to see if a feature like this could be possible in C++.

*Although dynamic data types can be kinda simulated in C++: `std::any`, container classes or structures.*

Comment: "I'm trying to understand how std::variant handles returning multiple types from its constructors." <- So why don't you ask a question about _that_ instead? Of course, try looking at some implementation first.

Comment: @Lapys: "*I'm trying to understand how std::variant handles returning multiple types from its constructors.*" Well, `variant` doesn't do that, so your question is kind of moot. You are *required* to provide a compile-time index/type to `std::get<variant>`. So it doesn't look at all like your interface.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use a mix of template function and `if constexpr` (C++17):

```
template<typename T>
T valueOf() const {
    if constexpr(std::is_same<T, bool>) return _boolValueOf();
    else if constexpr(std::is_same<T, int>) return _intValueOf();
    else if constexpr(std::is_same<T, std::string>) return _std_stringValueOf();
}
```

Requires passing the type, but then the signature could be:

```
template<typename T>
T valueOf(const T& d) const {
    if constexpr(std::is_same<T, bool>) return _boolValueOf(d);
    else if constexpr(std::is_same<T, int>) return _intValueOf(d);
    else if constexpr(std::is_same<T, std::string>) return _std_stringValueOf(d);
}
```

Comment: Under the convenient assumption that the requested type is known at compile-time. In that case, there should not be differently named functions doing conceptually the same thing in the first place. There should be overloads for the supported types.

Comment: Yes, under this assumption, which makes sense because at some point you need to write something at compile time.

Comment: @KillzoneKid indeed, added the note.

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher Is there per-chance an alternative method? I understand the concept but I'm asking because my compiler seems to fail with the example code -- and removing the `constexpr` keyword causes each condition's return statements to be evaluated at compile time and throw an error.

Comment: You need then to have a SFINAE fucntion for each type with enable_if :/

Comment: @LogicStuff in the `valueOf()` case, it needs to be a template, because you can't overload on only the return type. It could be implemented as a bunch of specialisations instead of the `if constexpr` chain

Answer (score 2):

High-level and recomended solution is `std::any`, `std::variant`, `std::optional`. Low-level,  hackish dangerous, final solution is `union`, `void*,` `static_cast`...
If you want neither, there is no more left to try. Do you finally want to do it in C++?

If are interested in the implementation of  those high-level facilities, you can check the source code on open source implementations. But you will eventually find that those implementations device the low level constructs pointed above.

Comment: Why `optional`? That's not at all helpful in this scenario.

Comment: In my interpretation, It has two return types: error or value. I have a nasty habit of generalization. Though not technically the case, I practically consider variant as a  superset of optional and a subset of any.

Answer (score 1):

First to have different return types you need to use a template to differentiate the functions. Then you can call `var(true).valueOf<bool>()` for example. You will have to specify the template on every call so the compiler knows what function (and return type) to use. This can't be deduced on it's own.

Secondly the var.type is a string that can only be checked at runtime. So `var(42).valueOf<bool>()` compiles just fine. You would have to check var.type against the template argument at runtime and throw an exception when the types don't match.

Not an ideal design.

Answer (score 0):

For you `valueOf` function, imo, [user-defined conversion](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cast_operator) is also a choice:

```
operator std::string()
    {
        return primitive_value._char_pointer;
    }
    operator bool()
    {
        return primitive_value._bool;
    }
    operator int()
    {
        return primitive_value._int;
    }
    ......
```

Then you can use like this:

```
var v1("hello");
var v2(true);
var v3(10);
std::string a = v1;
bool b = v2;
int c = v3;

std::cerr << static_cast<std::string>(v1) << '\n';
std::cerr << std::boolalpha << static_cast<bool>(v2) << '\n';
std::cerr << static_cast<int>(v3) << '\n';
```

If you still hope to use function, just add a `operator()`:

```
var
operator()()
{
    return *this;
}
```

Then you can:

```
var v1("hello");
var v2(true);
var v3(10);
std::string a = v1();
bool b = v2();
int c = v3();
```

But still a little ugly, right? Just add your `valueOf` function:

```
var
valueOf()
{
    return *this;
}
```

Then:

```
var v1("hello");
var v2(true);
var v3(10);
std::string a = v1.valueOf();
bool b = v2.valueOf();
int c = v3.valueOf();
```

But these solutions have many limitions. `if constexpr` provided by Matthieu Brucher is more powerful. Just all about provide a idea here : ). 
**But please note, unlike if constexpr, the ways I provided is not really multiple types return**, just user-defined conversion.

Of course, there are more solutions, like sfinae(use enable_if and is_same in return type), or tag dispatch, but both of them require template